# use a private git repository with read the docs

Tags: read-the-docs

I installed read-the-docs to produce documentation starting from projects on a private git repository which needs user/password authentication.

When import manually a project, how can I put user and password to allow read-the-docs to clone the repo?

Many thanks,
Max

Answer (score 5):

I've recently faced the same problem. There's one more question like this here
[Why can't I clone a git repo for readthedocs to build the documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654785/why-cant-i-clone-a-git-repo-for-readthedocs-to-build-the-documentation) where the author gave [his own conclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31673105/8604951) about the problem.

As documented by the folks at Read the Docs themselves, here - [Read the Docs Open Source Philosophy](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/open-source-philosophy.html#read-the-docs-open-source-philosophy), they provide free official support only for open source projects through [readthedocs.org](https://readthedocs.org). While further documentations as provided here - [Read the Docs for Business](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/commercial/index.html#read-the-docs-for-business) suggests using [readthedocs.com](https://readthedocs.com) for *business/commercial purposes* only. As I can understand, usage of a private repo assumes that the software is not open source.

A few days later, I received the following email from the support (I asked about VS Online in particular):

> We don't support private repositories on our community site,
> readthedocs.org -- it is for open source software only. We don't
> support VSTS or VS Online directly with our commercial hosting, but
> there is at least support for SSH cloning of repositories. I'd suggest
> trialing an account there if your software is not open source.

Comment: @habib which code are you writing about? I think, this answer doesn't assume any code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're running a local clone of readthedocs.org.
To allow SSH cloning of private repos, you can create a file /readthedocs/settings/local_settings.py (if not already done) and add following setting:

```
ALLOW_PRIVATE_REPOS = True
```

Just make sure the user rtd is running as, has SSH pubkey access to the repo.