# Problem setting up Github webhook for ReadTheDocs

Tags: github, read-the-docs

I'm starting to use ReadTheDocs for the first time and trying to connect it to my GitHub repo. When I go into the repo on Github, select Settings then select Webhooks from the menu I thought it was supposed to display a dropdown list of webhooks, including ReadThe Docs. Instead there is no list, just an Add Webhook button which takes me to a page to set up a custom webhook.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an easier way to connect your repo to ReadTheDocs is to go from the readTheDocs side.  Signing up for your RTD account, there is an option to signup with GitHub.

After specifying your GH account info, on your RTD account dashboard there will be an option to 'Import a Project' which will list all of the repositories associated with your GitHub account.

From there you can select which repo you want to import. RTD will automatically generate the webhooks and start building the docs.

Have a look at these resources if you haven't already:
*https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/connected-accounts.html#connecting-your-account

*https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/webhooks.html#webhook-creation

Comment: Thanks I tried that.  I do seem to be connected.  If (in readthedocs) I go to Settings/Admin/Connected Services it shows my Github account as connected. If I then go to Import a Project it shows: "No remote repositories found, try refreshing your accounts".  If I click the "refresh your accounts" link it chews on it for a bit but still shows no repos.  Seems like I'm connected to Github but RTD can't see my repos.  BTW they are all private but not sure that makes any difference (I created a test public one and RTD still couldn't find it).

Comment: I think that using private github repos will require a commercial   subscription to RTD.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46907540/use-a-private-git-repository-with-read-the-docs https://github.com/rtfd/readthedocs.org/issues/3258

Comment: That’s a good point. I have no problem with making it public but it’s very much a work in progress so I was originally hoping to get it to a half-decent state, including docs, first. Anyway I’ll try again with a test public repo to see if that was the issue.